# Remove the Shadow in Bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When I have data inside of the input, the shadow will display in the input's background and I want to remove it in bootstrap 2.

I just want a white background in the input box only.

Please remember that I'm using bootstrap 2!

Thanks!

http://jsbin.com/vuzikonazu/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-shadow:none;` in input class as below

```
.text-input-wrapper input {
  border:none;
  background:none;
  outline:none;
  padding:0 0;
  margin:0 0;
  font:inherit;
  box-shadow:none;

}
```